# Unsure how to map unknown values in JS (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to pass unknown values into a component within react.   i need to pass it in as a list of key value pairs.  i have put together the below example to explain the problem

```
this.myArray = [];
this.my2ndArray = [];
this.arraytouse = [];

this.myArray.push({"x": "test", "y": "test", "z": "test"});
this.myArray.push({"x": "test", "y": "test", "z": "test"});
this.myArray.push({"x": "test", "y": "test", "z": "test"});

this.my2ndArray.push({"a": "test", "b": "test", "c": "test"});
this.my2ndArray.push({"a": "test", "b": "test", "c": "test"});
this.my2ndArray.push({"a": "test", "b": "test", "c": "test"});

if(Math.Random(10) > 5)
{
  this.arraytouse = this.myArray;
}
else
{
  this.arraytouse = this.my2ndArray;
}

this.myItems = this.arraytouse.map((f) => {
  return {
    x: f.x,
    y: f.y,
    z: f.z
  }
});
```

this will work assuming the random returns a value > 5 however it will fail if it is below 5.   the desired behaviour is for the return values to look like it is if the value is above 5,  but if it is 5 or below it would look like the below:

```
return {
    a: f.a,
    b: f.b,
    c: f.c
  }
```

This is just a sample to explain the problem,  my end state solution is pulling this list from a database so it could be a completely variable set of values returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, `x = f.x` is a syntax error. Also, any specific reason of doing `map( f => { return {x: f.x ...} })`? Do you need any specific properties only?

Comment: i am using office fabric pre-built components. the display list uses the first value of a keyvalue pair as the "columnName"   that it's being mapped to.  you are right,  it should have been x: f.x y: f.y   etc.   in this case i might be putting 4 items into the displayList  each one with 3 columns (a, b, c) and thier respective values in the list.   this codepen is what i am talking about.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLqvOQ  i want to be able to call the same component by passing in the items list. but that items list could be different based on the columns being returned from my datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get your need

```
arraytouse.map(obj => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,o)=>{
    acc[o] = obj[o]
    return acc
  }, {})
})
```

In simple form

```
arraytouse.map(obj => {
     var robj = {}
     for(o in obj) robj[o] = obj[o]
     return robj
})
```